# Обработчик события во время изменения адресной строки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

На странице есть обычный линк с якорем (пример: `<a href="#top">TOP</a>`)

В JavaScript (лучше если это будет jQuery) нужен обработчик события, изменения адресной строки. А именно по нажатию такого якорю, прописать нужный триггер на события.

Что-то типо такого (далее наркоманские мечты автора):

```
jQuery(window.location.href).change(function(){   });
```

Задача кажется элементарной, но решения я не нашёл =(

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При переходе по якорю меняется не url, а `hash`.
Можно подписаться на событие [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/hashchange)

```js
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e) {
  document.getElementById('o').innerHTML = e.oldURL;
  document.getElementById('n').innerHTML = e.newURL;
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="#top">TOP</a>
<a href="#top2">TOP2</a>
<a href="#top3">TOP3</a>
<a href="#top4">TOP4</a>

<div id="o"></div>
<div id="n"></div>
```

То же самое с jQuery

```js
$(window).on("hashchange", function(e) {
  document.getElementById('o').innerHTML = e.originalEvent.oldURL;
  document.getElementById('n').innerHTML = e.originalEvent.newURL;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#top">TOP</a>
<a href="#top2">TOP2</a>
<a href="#top3">TOP3</a>
<a href="#top4">TOP4</a>

<div id="o"></div>
<div id="n"></div>
```

Comment: Grundy, спасибо большое! Максимально развёрнутый и подробный ответ. Решились сразу все вопросы) Мира в твоём доме :3